# Vagrant + Ansible + Python3

Tags: python, vagrant, ansible, vagrantfile

I have a `Vagrantfile` that is simplified to:

```
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
  config.vm.box = "ubuntu/xenial64"
  config.vm.boot_timeout = 900

  config.vm.define 'srv' do |srv|
    srv.vm.provision 'ansible' do |ansible|
      ansible.compatibility_mode = '2.0'
      ansible.playbook = 'playbook.yml'
    end
  end
end
```

When I run `vagrant provision`, at the `Gathering Facts` stage, I get `/usr/bin/python: not found` because Ubuntu 16.04 by default only has `python3` not Python 2.x `python` installed.

I see several older posts about this. It seems recent versions of Ansible support using Python 3, but it must be configured via `ansible_python_interpreter=/usr/bin/python3` in the hosts file or on the ansible command line. Is there any way I specify this option in my `Vagrantfile` or in my `playbook.yml` file? I'm currently not using a hosts file, I'm not running `ansible-playbook` via command line, I'm running Ansible through the Vagrant integration.

FYI, I'm using Ansible 2.4.1.0 and Vagrant 2.0.1, which are the latest  versions as of this writing.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

As far as I know, you can use in Vagrant file `extra_vars`  make sure put it inside of ansible scope.

```
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
  config.vm.box = "ubuntu/xenial64"
  config.vm.boot_timeout = 900

  config.vm.define 'srv' do |srv|
    srv.vm.provision 'ansible' do |ansible|
      ansible.compatibility_mode = '2.0'
      ansible.playbook = 'playbook.yml'
      ansible.extra_vars = { ansible_python_interpreter:"/usr/bin/python2" }
    end
  end
end
```

In above block `extra_vars` was set up with`ansible_python_interpreter` or you can use  `host_vars` like this:

```
ansible.host_vars = {
        "default" => {
            "ansible_python_interpreter" => "/usr/bin/python2.7"
        }
    }
```

Comment: `ansible_python_interpreter: '/usr/bin/python3'` in the `extra_vars` section worked perfectly, thanks!

Comment: For some strange reason, Ansible started looking for my local Python (installed on macOS via Homebrew) on a local cluster I was managing with Vagrant (`/bin/sh: 1: /usr/local/opt/python@2/bin/python2.7: not found`), so explicitly defining it with `ansible.extra_vars` was required to fix the connection issue. I'm guessing I have set the interpreter somewhere else errantly :/

Comment: Ah, just found out why—it's my own silly role that's overwriting `ansible_python_interpreter` (see: https://github.com/geerlingguy/ansible-role-k8s_manifests/issues/3).

Comment: Ha, third time in a year I've come back to this answer. Thanks again @julian salas!